# QueryFailedError: the column "price" contain null values - TypeORM - PostgreSQL

Tags: node.js, postgresql, typescript, typeorm

I've created a simple table:

```
import { Column, Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from "typeorm"

@Entity()
export class Test {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    public id!: number

    @Column({ nullable: false })
    public name!: string

    @Column({ nullable: false, type: "float" })
    public price!: number
}
```

I generate the migration and run it also. When I have no data in the database and I run the server it succeed. But when I add 1 row in the database and I run it again it appears the following error:

`QueryFailedError: the column «price» contain null values`

The databse definetely has the row with all the data. I tried a lot of cases and none of them was correct.

Has anybody some idea for it?

Comment: How are you insertiing the data?

Comment: Did you figure it out? I'm having the same issue. I get the error even though there are values.

Comment: It is also possible you have `synchronize: "false"` (value as string), and that will be evaluated to `true` (`Boolean('false')` is true). So be sure you have `synchronize: false` (as a boolean) in your ORM configuration. The most voted answer below contains the details.

Answer (score 56):

I had a similar issue, and I reported it at the bottom of [this thread](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/2108).

You probably have `synchronize: true` on your ORM configuration. Because of this, every time you run your app Typeorm tries to create the tables. If you have data in your DB, it throws that misleading error.

From [here](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/connection-options.md):

> synchronize - Indicates if database schema should be auto created on every application launch. Be careful with this option and don't use this in production - otherwise you can lose production data. This option is useful during debug and development. As an alternative to it, you can use CLI and run schema:sync command. Note that for MongoDB database it does not create schema, because MongoDB is schemaless. Instead, it syncs just by creating indices.

Answer (score 25):

### The Problem

This line of code right here is the troublemaker:

```
@Column({ nullable: false, type: "float" })
public price!: number
```

You have set `nullable: false`, which means you never want this column to be null.

Why is this giving you trouble?

Because you already have rows in your database that don't have an entry for this column.

Remember:

Prior to this migration, the column didn't exist. But now you're running a migration to add a new column.

But TypeORM needs a way to handle the existing rows...

So, if you were TypeORM, what value would you assign by default if the column didn't exist? Probably `NULL`. Which is exactly what it does. And that's why the error.

### How do you fix this issue?

There are two ways here.

#### Very easy way

Set a default value in the `ColumnOptions`

```
@Column({ nullable: false, type: "float", default: 0.0 })
public price!: number
```

#### DANGER: The nuclear option

Delete all data from the table, then re-run the migration.

In Postgres PSQL:

```
DELETE FROM test;
```

Comment: I do not understand why deleting the table solves the problem.

Comment: You are not deleting the table. Rather, deleting data from the table. Doing so removes rows that do not have the column set, which will be set to NULL post-migration.

Comment: I have the same problem with columns that already exist or are modified.

Answer (score 5):

I had this entity

```
import {Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column} from "typeorm";

@Entity()
export class User {

@PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
id!: number;

@Column('text')
firstName!: string;

}
```

and I was getting the error "column "firstName" contains null values."
So I added {nullable: true} as @pleerock suggested here https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/845  and it worked.

```
import {Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column} from "typeorm";

@Entity()
export class User {

@PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
id!: number;

@Column('text', {nullable: true})
firstName: string;

}
```

Answer (score 5):

Set **"synchronize": false** in *ormconfig.json* will fix this issue:

```
{
   ....
   "synchronize": false,
   ....
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. You can set a default value and `nullable: true` as said before.
Also, what helped me was to delete the `.dist` folder in order to recreate it on the build with the new changes.

Comment: to me, simply restarting the server make it work.

Answer (score 0):

What if you delete the `nullable` declaration or what if you set it to `true` ...

Then you can do the `nullable` check using validation decorators from [class-validator](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. It looks like when you add a new column without a default value, the default value of the column will be `null` and typeorm will not allow that if you don't explicitly specify that it's ok to be `null`

For me it worked after I had added in the `@Column({nullable: true})`. This tells typeorm that it's ok to have `null` in the column.

Or as @nathanl93 suggested, you could give a default value  `@Column({default: 'aDefaultValue'})` and the new column will be added with the specified default value every time if no other value will be specified.

You will need to make sure that you have the parameter `"syncronize": true` where you have configured your connection to the db. For me it was the `ormconfig.json` file.

Comment: This is useful info, but not a satisfactory answer b/c I don't want the new column to be nullable

Answer (score 0):

This will also happen when you change a column type even if there are no null values in the column.

Ironically I had it happen to me with a column called "currency" in a table called "Price", so your question was eerily close. I checked the database and confirmed all values were 'USD' (it's a new app we only support one currency at the moment).

What had changed was I changed the decorator from `@Column()` to `@Column('text')`. So for anyone else who stumbles around looking, adding `{default:"USD"}` worked for me.

It was better than going `{nullable:true}` since I never want that column empty.

Even more weirdly, I was able to remove the declaration after running sync once. Though once again, I confirmed there were never any null rows.

Answer (score 0):

for anyone with this issue, adding a default value, changing the nullable setting, or even removing the existing data are not solutions.

you don't have to change your column's metadata

this issue happens when you either change the nullable value from false to true for a column that already has null values

or when you change a column's type, for example from string into an enum even if there is no existing null value at all

the solution is easy and straightforward, all you have to do is:

1- fill or change the existing values to satisfy the new column's definitions
i.e. set a non-null value, and make sure all values are of the new type or existing on the specified enum
2- change `nullable` to true and after a successful build revert it back into false