# Typeorm Migrations - How to deal with 'column "<column_name>" contains null values' errors in production

Tags: sql, postgresql, typeorm

The main problem I want to discuss is the schema synchronization conflicts that occur when tables already have data and some new required attribute is added or I rename an required attribute. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52064130/queryfailederror-the-column-price-contain-null-values-typeorm-postgresql/55994448#55994448) already has some possible solutions but these are not acceptable in a production environment where you already have user data since they simply suggest to delete the data. I also want to enforce required fields so setting the column to `{nullable: true}` is also not an option for me.

As an example suppose I had a column named "time" that I renamed to "minutes". When I synchronize the schemas TypeORM produces the following error:

```
QueryFailedError: column "minutes" contains null values
```

Is there a more elegant/automated way to deal with these errors other than just setting the column to `{nullable: true}`? I can imagine that you could write some custom SQL with the migration script to also modify the row values. Seems like a little to much manual effort for me though.

Comment: Add a NOT NULL column constraint.

Comment: What do you want to happen with the existing null values?

Comment: @jarlh either directly map them to the new column or modify them slighty and then map them